# canon IR C3380 driver

Tags: printing, canon

I need to configure a Canon IR C3380 printer. I have not found drivers for it (it says is not necessary). Can you tell me which driver or protocol I must install?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following site:

http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010366.asp

then choose the OS (in your case I am assuming you are using Ubuntu, if yes then you can choose Linux) then select your preferred language and click on submit.

Based on your Ubuntu installation choose either 32bit Deb or 64Bit Deb.